# Font Awesome one Icon stopped displaying on Homepage in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, icons, font-awesome

http://test.nowitconnects.com/
http://test.nowitconnects.com/about-us/

The font awesome icon fa-user-circle-o next to "support center" stopped showing up on my wordpress homepage!? But it displays just fine on interior pages. I can also swapped it out with a different icon and it works, but not with fa-user-circle or fa-user-circle-0. What changed?

Thanks!

Comment: Inner page is loading the font awesome from plugin called dhvc-form. Please check with home page too.

Answer (score 2):

You're loading several different versions of Font Awesome. The last one loads on line 679 when I view the source code.

There is no Font Awesome icon for fa-user-circle-o in your last Font Awesome CSS loaded. (Use cmd+f or ctrl+f to search for fa-user-circle-o after following the link below.)

http://test.nowitconnects.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/bower/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css?ver=5.0.1